# Django admin: pass variable by URL

Tags: django, django-admin

i want to pass a variable by URL to another page in django admin.
it seems it is not working,  i want to pass the variable "/?name=hello", and catch it by request.GET.get["name",""].but the url becomes "/?e=1" after it passed. 
if i use the default parameter'q', it works, but it will have a conflict. 
it seems this problem is django-admin only. and i need pass it by url not post...
does any one knows how to solve this problem

thanks

Comment: Doesn't make sense, `request.GET.get["name",""]` would cause `TypeError`.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that the lookup `name` does not exist when the `get_query_set` tries to resolve it as a model field. Thus an `IncorrectLookupParameters()` exception is raised which in turn redirects to the not very helpful "e=1" url. This problem is solved in Django 1.4 with the introduction of custom filterspecs. Until then one possible solution is to dynamically overwrite the `ChangeList` class returned by your `ModelAdmins` `get_changelist()` method.

This solution works on Django 1.3:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        changelist_class = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_changelist(request, 
                                                                 **kwargs)

        class CustomChangeList(changelist_class):
            def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                self._name = request.GET.get('name')
                super(CustomChangeList, self).__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)

            def get_query_set(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if self._name:
                    del self.params['name']

                qs = super(CustomChangeList, self).get_query_set(*args, **kwargs)

                if self._name:
                    return qs.filter([FILTER WHAT YOU WANT HERE...])

                return qs


        return CustomChangeList
```

Comment: Happens to me in Django 2.0 if there is more than one parameter, e.g. `endpoint/?a=b&c=d` . Works fine with single parameter like `endpoint/?a=b`

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain your problem a bit more....why do you want to pass a variable to django admin... 
also you cant catch GET variable like this...
Either use:

```
request.GET['name']
```

or

```
request.GET.get('name','')
```

.get is a instancemethod not a dictionary.

Comment: i used it request.GET.get('name',''). 
i want to pass the varible to admin to tell, which reports to show up. 
q=0 to show the reports who submitted. q=1 to show the rpoets who is been assigned and etc.

Comment: i can only do that by use parameter q. which q is used by search filed. it was fine. but now i need to use search field. and q will be used for that. so i need to really fix it.

Comment: u may think why i dont think POST. that reason is that, if there is more reports that one page can show. djang admin use p=1, p=2 to use multiple pages to show all report. but if i dont use GET it will loose track

Comment: Can you post your models. Do you want to filter the admin site results ? I think what you want is a list_filter = ['field1', 'field2'] option  in the admin.py of your model.
This will add a filter similar to what you want to achieve through get.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the question is still unanswered and similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494200/django-admin-custom-change-list-arguments-override-e-1/56445221#56445221?newreg=c632538e09ea47e2be87d72f9138f2c8). meesterguyperson posted there [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56445221/16540073), go check it out.

The solution is to create a "fake filter" that will register a URL parameter with django but will not affect the queryset and admin site appearance.

I adapted meesterguyperson's answer a bit myself and instead of using a blank template to hide the "fake filter", I simply exclude it from the filter pane by returning False from has_output method.

```
from django.contrib.admin.filters import SimpleListFilter

class KwargPassThroughFilter(SimpleListFilter):
title = ''

# hide from filter pane
def has_output(self):
    return False

# these two function below must be implemented for SimpleListFilter to work
# (any implementation that doesn't affect queryset is fine)
def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    return (request.GET.get(self.parameter_name), ''),

def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    return queryset
```

Now, you can subclass this filter and override the parameter_name with the desired name of your param, e.g.

```
class NameKwargPassThroughFilter(KwargPassThroughFilter):
    parameter_name = 'name'
```

and append register the filter in the ModelAdmin subclass

```
class SomethingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    list_filter = (
        ...,
        NameKwargPassThroughFilter,
        ...,
    )

    ...
```

At this point, you can freely use the param in the URL and access it within the scope of SomethingAdmin pages...

Works for Django 3.0+