# Django Admin Custom Queryset. prevent e=1

Tags: python, django

I have a need to enter product ids in the url of my admin page but Django does not allow me to.

This is my function that does work.

```
    def get_queryset(self, request):
      qs = super(LaptopStockAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)

      pid = request.GET.get('pid')
      if pid is not None:
        ids = [int(id) for id in pid.split(',')]
        return qs.filter(id__in=ids)
      else:
        return qs
```

It gets the objects related to the ids but then Django refreshes the page and ads ?e=1 after the URL.

This is a security related problem and I cannot find a suitable solution.

I have tried [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494200/django-admin-custom-change-list-arguments-override-e-1) but they don't work for my specific case.

Is there a way to not create a list filter and where the results are shown in the admin page?

Comment: Maybe you will find your answer here: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2322/ or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/filters/#using-a-simplelistfilter

Comment: Thanks for the link. I came across it earlier but I want to keep the default admin page

Comment: That's exactly what that shows. Have you opened the docs? The second link I provided.

Comment: This outputs the filters on the page which I don't want