# Named groups in Django admin urls

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

Is there a way to modify the Django admin to accept named groups in all admin URLs? For example, I would like to be able to say

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    url(r'^/admin/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/', include(custom_admin.site.urls))
)
```

However, visiting `/admin/2014` gives a `TypeError`, saying that `index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'year'`. How can I pass URL parameters along to the admin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497062/django-admin-pass-variable-by-url

Answer (score -1):

correct your URL

```
?P<year>[0-9]{4})
```

it should be like this

Comment: ?P<year>[0-9]{4})

Comment: @Petter Friberg What is the point in your edit man i cant understand ?

Comment: Just trying to improve readability, if you don't like it rollback.